# samba config for guest users

Tags: linux, windows, samba, file-server

win10 has disabled SMB2 guest account. If I try samba standard config below works with win7.

The workaround on win10 is re-enable SMB2 guest account from clients:

```
Open the Local Group Policy editor
Go to Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\Lanman Workstation
For the setting, "Enable insecure guest logons" right click and choose Edit.
Choose "Enabled" and click Ok
```

works!

My problem is that I don't want change this key to all windows clients but If I don't make any changes I cannot totally connect to my fileserver:

```
"Windows cannot access \\DEBIAN10-1"
```

My goal (for some win 10 clients) access to password protected shared folders without make changes to local group policy editor

```
cat /etc/samba/smb.conf

[global]
        security = user
        map to guest = Bad User 
        nobody = guest
        netbios name = debian10-1
        guest account = nobody 
        log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log

[public]
        comment = Public share
        path = /home/user/
        guest ok = yes
        read only = no
        force user = nobody
        force group = nobody
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775

[no public]
        path=/home/nopublic
        guest ok = no
        admin users = root 
        valid users = user1, user2, user3, user4, user,5
```